# NBitcoin Не удаётся создать транзакцию

Tags: c#, .net, bitcoin, nbitcoin

Следующий код создаёт bitcoin-транзакцию с 1 входом и 1 выходом. Адреса отправителя и получателя совпадают. fundingTx - существующая транзакция с 1 непотраченным выходом, senderAddresses - массив `NBitcoin.BitcoinAddress` c 1 элементом - адрес отправителя (включает и приватный ключ), coin - выход fundingTx с индексом 0 (первый и единственный), recipient - получатель (`NBitcoin.BitcoinAddress`, тот же адрес, что и отправитель), fees - комиссия за транзакцию (корректное значение в сатошах).

```
Transaction tx1 = Transaction.Parse(fundingTxHexString, Network.Main);
Coin coin = new Coin(tx1, 0);

TransactionBuilder builder = Network.CreateTransactionBuilder();
builder.AddCoins(new[] { coin });
builder.AddKeys(senderAddresses.Select((sender) => sender.PrivateKey).ToArray());
builder.SendFees(new Money(fees));
builder.SetChange(changeAddress.Address.ScriptPubKey);
builder.SendAllRemainingToChange();
builder.Send(recipient, value);

Transaction transaction = builder.BuildTransaction(true);
```

В результате иногда я получаю вот такую ерунду:

```
{
    "addresses": [
        "bc1qmystncn6phsrtex5hchtulwvwrqj7gl79qe2zk"
    ],
    "block_height": -1,
    "block_index": -1,
    "confirmations": 0,
    "double_spend": false,
    "fees": 0,
    "hash": "f6ef6ddbb30eedde0695a4a6967c1bb97742e58f22007906783d3c20b102f215",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "age": 0,
            "output_index": 0,
            "prev_hash": "b4111fb1bf6ec9ca3875b468eb02bb47c433a77e459a498b643e63fa1633fa66",
            "script_type": "empty",
            "sequence": 4294967295
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "addresses": [
                "bc1qmystncn6phsrtex5hchtulwvwrqj7gl79qe2zk"
            ],
            "script": "0014d920b9e27a0de035e4d4be2ebe7dcc70c12f23fe",
            "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash",
            "value": 1595000
        }
    ],
    "preference": "low",
    "received": "2022-07-13T22:52:24.566309859Z",
    "relayed_by": "44.200.190.150",
    "size": 191,
    "total": 1595000,
    "ver": 1,
    "vin_sz": 1,
    "vout_sz": 1,
    "vsize": 110
}
```

То есть проблема с тем как обрабатывается `coin`. При этом `builder.Verify` возвращает `true`, то есть транзакция сформирована "корректно". Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: А где и как вы это реализуете?

Comment: Настольный btc кошелёк. Пользователь добавляет приватные ключи и распоряжается своими средствами. Иногда нужно ускорить транзакцию - отправить средства с выхода существующей транзакции на тот же адрес (с этим есть проблемы).